# android notification background color is not white on lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

As we known that Android lollipop force set the notification background color to white, so we can set the style of TextView according to different sdk version by putting style.xml in folder values-v21.

So here comes my question, on some third party ROMs, for example, the EMUI developed by Huawei tech co., the background of notification is not white(nearly black), by setting style to

```
android:TextAppearance.Material.Notification.Title
```

the color of the text is almost black, as a result, we cannot see the text clearly. I had been searching the internet for almost two days but find nothing helps.

I am trying to get the color of the notification background and set the text color dynamically, but I don't know how to accomplish this.

Need your help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I just use the official API to set the notification info, that would inflate the default notification layout (*status_bar_latest_event_content.xml*）instead of my custom layout.
The rom changed the default background and text-color of the *status_bar_latest_event_content.xml*, but it wouldn't (or can't) change the custom layout.

```
mBuilder.setLargeIcon(combineBitmap).setContentText(notifyString).setSubText("fff");
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `android:targetSdkVersion="21"` from manifest.xml. it will work! and from this there is no prob at all in your apk it just a trick i apply this and i found colorful icon in notification and all features will remain same which u earlier use

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know that since Lollipop android would force set the background to white, and change the icon by ColorFilter, but I won't change the `targetSdkVersion `  for some other reasons. That's why I asked  this question.

Comment: i just asked for remove not change just remove after that it will also run on any target adk